# Invert alpha png picture

Tags: html, css

I have small icon png picture which contains white and alpha (transparent) pixels. Can I somehow "invert" that icon using css (prefered) or javascript to get:

white pixel -> transparent pixel

transparent pixel -> white pixel

I see there are some new css properties like filter and mask but not all major browser support them.

Comment: There are now two viable answers, one with exactly what you were asking for and another giving a viable workaround, so please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest and quickest way would be to just create a second image that is already inverted. Assuming you wanted to invert the picture on hover, you could use the :hover css class to swap out the 2 images.

```
    #divId:hover{background-image: url('imageName.ext') }
```

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript you can do all sorts of pixel manipulation, but I warn you that it is not a quick path and Internet Explorer 8 and older will not work.

I would recommend you to use two separate images as Tyler Crady suggested, but since you asked...

Here is the code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('channelconvert');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    // Draw this image with offset 0x0
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  }
  image.src = 'test.png';

  function invert() {
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var pixels = imageData.data;

    // Loop through set of fours due to four color channels: red, green, blue, alpha
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
      // Ensure that all color channels are fully white
      pixels[i] = 255;                      // Red channel
      pixels[i + 1] = 255;                  // Green channel
      pixels[i + 2] = 255;                  // Blue channel
      pixels[i + 3] = 255 - pixels[i + 3];  // Alpha channel
    }

    imageData.data = pixels;

    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  }

  // Convert channel
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', invert, false);

  // Reset to the original state
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', invert, false);
});
```

...and [here is a quick demo](http://alphachannel.kaktus.cc/) so you can check out the HTML part, which is fairly simple.

Comment: I want to emphasize that this is slightly processor intensive as it uses JavaScript to do the pixel magick, probably not suitable for that wide use. Some years ago I did a similar image editing on iPad 2 and after some 10 layers it took several seconds to finish a 700x500 canvas. I had to resort to either canvas or server side code because some layers had effects like Photoshop's multiply and such.