# Invert alpha value of a canvas image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, alpha

What is the best way to invert the alpha channel of a canvas' content?

I have seen solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363074/invert-alpha-png-picture/19369083#19369083) where you can go through pixel-by-pixel and re-map the alpha value, but this is an expensive operation, and I was hoping that there might be something more performant (or better practice) method, such as a way of using `context.filter` or something similar to do this.

As a simplified example, given this image, where all pixels have the same RGB channel (black) values but varying alpha channel values:

[image]

I would like to produce this image where the RGB channels are unchanged:

[image]

Note that there are a range of alpha values in the original and final images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `globalCompositeOperation` to invert the color with alpha.

1. Source image with radial gradient.
2. Result image with inverted alpha.
3. Checking the result: drawing result image on top of yellow background

```js
const src_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas#source');
const src_ctx = src_canvas.getContext('2d');

const result_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas#result');
const result_ctx = result_canvas.getContext('2d');

const check_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas#check');
const check_ctx = check_canvas.getContext('2d');

const w = src_canvas.width = result_canvas.width = check_canvas.width = 180;
const h = src_canvas.height = result_canvas.height = check_canvas.height = 180;

const gradient = src_ctx.createRadialGradient(w/2,h/2,0, w/2,h/2,w/3);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

src_ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
src_ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

result_ctx.drawImage(src_canvas,0,0);
result_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
result_ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h); // uses default fillStyle = 'black'

check_ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow'; // to check if the figure isn't fully opaque
check_ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

check_ctx.drawImage(result_canvas,0,0);
```

```html
<canvas id="source"></canvas>
<canvas id="result"></canvas>
<canvas id="check"></canvas>
```

It works only if the **base color of gradient** (your transparent image) and the **color for fillStyle** after applying `globalCompositeOperation="source-out"` is the same. If you have different colors in your transparent image - it wouldn't work.

I have black as base color of transparent image `rgba(0,0,0,...)` and black color as default for filling when `result_ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h)`. If, for example, base color of source image would be red (`'rgba(255,0,0,...)'`) then we had to explicitly define it before fillRect() -> `result_ctx.fillStyle = 'red' ('rgb(255,0,0)')`;